# Encode user input to prevent web page errors

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

99% of answers on this issue talk about how to sanitize input. I actually don't care in this case - the page is secured with users' logons.

All I want is to prevent page errors - I really don't care what the user types in.

So, this multi-line text box in theory means that users will cut + paste from Word, or some other editor with encodings.

Since a simple "<" or "[" the text can BLOW out the string entered by the user.

I of course serialize a few values into a JSON string.

Hence, I've been doing this:

```
            // transfer user comments box to Pinfo
            // but, user might type in crap like "<" etc. - not allowed
```

JavaScript:

```
            var MyUpLoadInfo = document.getElementById("MyUpLoadInfo")  // client side json pinfo
            var MyNotes = document.getElementById("txtNotes")
            Pinfo = JSON.parse(MyUpLoadInfo.value)
            // convert string to base64 - too much quotes and crap!!!
            var tnote = cleanup(MyNotes.value)
            Pinfo.txtNotes = window.btoa(tnote)
```

So, I've been using btoa to convert the string.

Server side, then I simple de-code that string with this:

```
    Dim sConvert As New UTF8Encoding

   cPinfo2.txtNotes = 
       sConvert.GetString((Convert.FromBase64String(cPinfo2.txtNotes)))
```

So, this works MOST of the time, and thus I do NOT care if the user types in say a "<", or a ":" or whatever.

However, I still every few days still get this error as a result of above:

```
Error Description:
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, 
more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding
characters.
```

I'm even happy to convert to a hex string.

Is there a simple encoding trick I can use client side, and then de-code server side that will prevent such errors?

I mean, I am thinking one solution would be to drop in a html editor, such as ckeditor, or use the ajax html editor I use for editing some content on the site.

Anyway, th goal is to prevent these errors, and I don't care if due to a simple cut + paste (say from word) that a few control characters and junk is included here.

I can and will consider stripping out any non printable characters, or even using + calling a sanitizer routine, but I want that text box content sent up to the server - by ANY MEANS possible!

As noted, the text box, and serialized to a json string works quite well, but when people started typing in things like

```
  [only this or that--
```

Then the open but not closed "]" things would blow out the JSON string (and de-serialize server side).

So, client side (js)

```
MyUpLoadInfo.value = JSON.stringify(Pinfo)
```

In fact, it really was the server side code to un-cork the above with:

```
    cPinfo2 = js.Deserialize(e.MyUpLoadInfo, GetType(ControlMIS.clsProjectInfo))
```

That would often error out (stray JSON values (characters like : or [ etc.) in the text box).

Anyway, the issue of the JSON string not a huge deal, but some type of "converting" to that user input into a hex string or ANYTHING at all at this point in time would suffice as a solution.

So, I can't seem to pin down what actually users are typing in, or is this is just some simple stray control characters in their text - but as I stated, I don't really care, I simple want that text string - whatever it may be.

Any good ideas on how to encode that string into something that will make the trip back up to the server?

Perhaps even encoding the string into a hex string?

## Edit: My solution based on answer

OK, so really the issue for me is due to the json.stringify. I need to pack up a few values AND ALSO the text box string. So, several values in that JSON string, and ALSO the text notes are to be passed back to the server.

That simple text Notes string was blowing up the json.stringfy, since stray "["or whatever would cause havoc with the json string.

So, proof of concept code (without the JSjsonON string just yet) is this:

```
        <h3>Input box</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"
            Height="169px" Width="510px" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="client side Enocde"
            OnClientClick="myencode();return false"
            />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="client side decode"
            OnClientClick="mydecode();return false"
            />
        <br />
        <br />

        <h3>Encoded text</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ClientIDMode="Static"
            Height="169px" Width="510px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />

         <h3>Server side de-coded text</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ClientIDMode="Static"
            Height="169px" Width="510px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="SERVER decode"
            OnClick="Button3_Click"
            />
```

The JS code:

```
    <script>
        function myencode() {

            var tbox1 = document.getElementById("TextBox1")  
            var tbox2 = document.getElementById("TextBox2")  
            var sText = encoder(tbox1.value)
            tbox2.value = sText
        }
        function mydecode() {

            var tbox1 = document.getElementById("TextBox1")  // client side json pinfo
            var tbox2 = document.getElementById("TextBox2")  // client side json pinfo
            var sText = decodeURIComponent(atob(tbox2.value));
            alert(sText)
            tbox1.value = sText
        }

        function encoder(s) {
            var sHex = btoa(encodeURIComponent(unescape(s)));
            return sHex
        }
    </script>
```

And the server side de-code:

```
Protected Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim sConvert As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim sBuf As String =
        sConvert.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(TextBox2.Text))

    Dim strMyResult As String =
        Uri.UnescapeDataString(sBuf)

    TextBox3.Text = strMyResult

End Sub
```

And the result is this:

[image]

So, I will now then try this "proof" of concept in production.

It is ONLY the one value (txtNotes) out of a JSON string that was causing issues with my code - and "rare" this would occur, but I never could track down what characters or what the user input that was causing issues here.

The above is only a test of the encode and then taking that text server side and un-encoding. The actual production code is of course a serialized JSON object, being sent to server side via a ajax call. However, the basic concept of "encoding" the text box input as a string is the "gold" part of the moving parts here.

Comment: I really think you've answered your own question.  Sanitize the content to fit your transport mechanic weather that be Json, hex or other.  Of course, I would still lean more to proactively preventing errors through validation rather than parking the ambulance at the bottom of the cliff

Comment: I'll just convert the text to some hex string, and be done with this. However, I am STILL rather curious as to what the suggested road here is. I mean, I don't care if user pasted in a image (in theory would become a base64 string), but then again, I kind of don't care. The simple matter is either a mac computer, or someone with non English settings is from time to time pasting in some stray characters - they are not a security issue, and thus it begs the question what people do in such cases. The fact of having a json serialized string "simple" blows out often without my simple btoa encode?

Comment: Well, if such simple things like a stray "[" blows this up, then how on earth does one serialize a few textbox values into a json string, but some stray "[" blows it up? Surely people must deal with this issue all the time. As I stated, I probably just write a bit of js code to create a hex string and be done with this.

Comment: I would still be more inclined to attempt to avoid the situation where a stray "[" blows things up by validating the user input.  I know you say in this case you don't really care, but you actually do because you don't want your app to blow up

Comment: Well, some text with a () or some simple characters in it should not take galactic efforts here. We not even talking about "<" or script tags. it just a simple plain jane multi-line text box. The built in security actually prevent most malicious content by default. This is a secured page logon wise anyway. A binary serializer client side, and then a correspond one server side would be rather nice.  The posted answer looks promising, but I now have to deal with "A       A" being returned server side as A%20%20%20%20%20A, and that's not what I want.  JSON.stringify is simply too fragile here.

Comment: >>ill be more inclined to attempt to avoid the situation where a stray "[" blows things up. --- yes, you are correct. I kind of want to just shove the issue under the carpet (don't all developers want to do that???? ;-)  ). I'll post some working code (that I just tested), and it looks to work quite nice. I'll have to toss out into production, and see how this goes. I suspect it some android phone in French language settings or some such is the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is good enough for the formation of image data URLs, it should be good enough for your needs:

```
 S=btoa(encodeURIComponent(unescape(S)));
```

To get the original string back...

```
 S=decodeURIComponent(atob(S));
```

Good luck with everything.

Comment: I'll have to give this a try - I do need code server side to un-cork this however.

Comment: Hum, server side will decode "A       A" as A%20%20%20%20%20A. So, I think a simple client side convert to hex values is going to be the road I take here.  I just think in this day and age I should not be having to write a loop to convert a simple string to hex to send that to the server. It only a simple text box - ouch!!!

Comment: Use unescape() to get the "A A"

Comment: but I need to do that server side. I send that content up as a json string. So, the real issue is JSON.stringify is too fragile here. So, sure, I can encode the string, then shove into the json string (with some other values). I now need to un-cork those values server side.

Comment: Ok, once again, THANK you very kindly - really appreciate this. I can decode server side. So, I'll toss this into the production code, and see how it goes!

Comment: Btw, for added safety you might want to encapsulate them in try{} catch(e){}

Comment: Yes, there is actually some code that cleans out the text box somewhat. I have posted an edit based on your answer. I'll try this code and roll out late tonight - see how it goes for a few days. As I stated, this does not occur very often, but it does trigger a in-valid base64 string, and hopefully this will fix.